# Fixing ampersands in YouTube embed codes when posting to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, youtube

I have a YouTube embed that ends in `?rel=0`.  I would like to change this to `?rel=0&vq=hd720`.  When I edit the post in WordPress under the Text editor, the query string becomes `?rel=0&amp;vq=hd720` which breaks the functionality.

How can I get WordPress to stop changing my link on this particular embed code in this post?

Edit: I can stay in Text-mode and delete the `amp;` from my embed code and click Update.  But then when I view source, WP has changed it to `&#038;`, which again breaks the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Change to the 'Text' tab on the post editor, edit your embed code url and save the post.
The button should be on the top right corner of the editor.

Comment: That was how I expected it to work.  Alas, WordPress adds `amp;` even in Text mode.

Comment: How about you post the entire HTML code over here? WP will not edit HTML code it can render

Comment: It's a simple embed code.  Your basic `<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/.../?rel=0"></iframe>` sort of embed in a Post.  Throw an ampersand in there and WP will encode it.  How do I tell it to quit that out?

Comment: Figured it out. DON'T switch back to Visual, just save the post.

Comment: Ahh, I thought we had it figured out!  If I view source, the embed code is now `?rel=0&#038;vq=hd720` Damnit, close.  That needs to be `?rel=0&vq=hd720`